# How can I rewrite a parent dictionary with the super command?

Tags: python, ironpython, super

The following code throws `__init__() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`. I am attempting to add to the dictionary in the parent class `Geometry` from the child `Enclosure`.

```py
class Geometry():
    def __init__(self, identifier='Geometry'):
        self.identifier = identifier 
        self.geom = {} 
        
    def pre(self, **param):
          print('*** Geom pre')
          
    def task(self, **param):
          print('*** Geom task')

    def run(self, **param):
        self.pre()
        self.task()
        self.post()
    def post(self, **param):
        print('*** Geom post')
        pass
```

```py
class Enclosure(Geometry):
    def __init__(self, identifier='Enclosure'):
        super().__init__(identifier=identifier)       
        self.geom[self.identifier] = {}
        self.geom[self.identifier] = {
        'lz': 4.5, #mm
        'lx': 34., #mm
        'ly': 30., #mm
        't': 1., #mm
        'r_edg': 1., #mm
        }
```

Comment: Works for me on Python3, but fails on Python2 as you describe. Any reason you still want to use an outdated Python version?

Comment: Yes unfortunately I am using a scripting tool within a CAD software and it is their version I have to deal with. I believe it's a form of Iron Python.